# How to Access Exposed BluePrism Webservices from a node js client from outside

Tags: web-services, virtual-machine, blueprism, rpa

i have created a blueprism process and exposed it as a webservice. So everything is working fine and i can see this webservice using below address format.

http://[machinename]:8181/ws/[processname].wsdl

So i could run a node js client application and was able to call this service and run the blueprism service from it. All those things are done inside a VMWare client machine. My blueprism software is installed inside this virtual machine client and i did the development there. ( this is not the host machine ). Now the problem is how can i access this exposed webservice from outside. I need to access this service as a public URL. Then i will be able to host my node js client application on cloud and can call this service to run the blueprism process. So could you please explain to me if this is going to work?

I have below questions.

a) Is this blueprism exposed webservice can be hosted as a public URL?

b) Should i do the blueprism development inside the host machine in the VMWare?

c) If there is a way to acceses blueprism webservices from outside the blueprism server environment. Please explain it to me.

d) Is new blueprism version support for these requirments?

e) Cant we host the exposed services directly in to a cloud enviroment?

Comment: The sample URL you've provided points to a WSDL file, which only *describes* the available functionality of a web service.

Answer (score 5):

## Before reading this, please be aware that what you're describing can become a large security risk if managed improperly.

These web services are generally meant for use within a logically secured segment of an enterprise network with *very* tight restrictions on the traffic sources that are allowed. Exposing these web services to the Internet can and will likely lead to the execution of Blue Prism Processes by third-party actors.

---

> a) Is this blueprism exposed webservice can be hosted as a public URL?

Sure can. It operates as a normal webservice, so you can place the Runtime Resource hosting this Blue Prism web service in a logical segment of the network that can be accessed externally.

> b) Should i do the blueprism development inside the host machine in the VMWare?

A bit irrelevant to the scope of the rest of your questions, but you'd generally do the development in an Interactive Client machine. Whether that is virtualized or not depends on your environment's setup.

When you complete the development of the Process providing the functionality of the web service and expose it in Blue Prism's System tab, it will propagate to the Runtime Resources in that environment.

> c) If there is a way to acceses blueprism webservices from outside the blueprism server environment. Please explain it to me.

See answer for question (a).

> d) Is new blueprism version support for these requirments?

Unclear exactly what you're asking here, but the latest version of Blue Prism does support exposing Processes and Objects as Web Services.

> e) Cant we host the exposed services directly in to a cloud enviroment?

If your Runtime Resource infrastructure is hosted in a cloud environment, the Web Service can be exposed from said environment.

The setup procedures and other information relevant to your questions regarding Web Services a Blue Prism environment are available in the Blue Prism Portal's Documents tab, in the documents titled "vX.x User Guide - Web Services".